# How to find data by funcion in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, nosql

I have a collection in mongodb using mongoose packages like below

```js
[
 {
    _id: new ObjectId("62ae97b6be08b688f93f2c07"),
    reportId: '1',
    method: 'A1',
    category: 'B2',
    date: '2022-06-19',
    time: '22:55',
    emergency: 'normal',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("62ae97b6be08b688f93f2c08"),
    reportId: '2',
    method: 'A3',
    category: 'B5',
    date: '2022-06-18',
    time: '23:05',
    emergency: 'normal',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("62ae97b6be08b688f93f2c09"),
    reportId: '3',
    method: 'A5',
    category: 'B1',
    date: '2022-06-19',
    time: '23:55',
    emergency: 'urgent',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

and I want to filter this data, and here is my find function()

```js
const options = [
 { method: { $in: ['A1','A2'] } },
 { emergency: { $in: data.emergency } },
 { category: { $in: data.category } }
];

const response = await Report.find({ $or: options,});
```

Until now, it works perfectly, but I still got one more filter: the `date` and `time` (They are all int type String).

I want to search for the range date and time between last night after 23 o'clock to 23 o'clock tonight.

But I have no idea how to write the query, please help me figure it out, thanks!!!

Here is my testing query:

```js
 date: {
       $where: function () {
              const yesterday = moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('YYYYMMDD') + '2300';
              const date = moment(this.date).format('YYYYMMDD') + this.time.replace(':', '');
              const today = moment().format('YYYYMMDD') + '2300';
              return yesterday < date && date <= today;
            },
          },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to first save dates in a format that supports comparators (lt, gt, etc.) such as a Timestamp or even a plain number. That way you can use MongoDB filters like this:

```
let filter = {
  date: { $gt: new Date(..), $lt: new Date(..) }
}

// This can be executed directly in the Mongo shell.
{
  created_on: {
    $gt: ISODate("1972-12-12"),
    $lt: ISODate('2022-06-019')
  }
}
```

But if you insist on using strings, then you would need to filter all your documents, and then parse each one to do your comparison.